# How to add/remove a subject when a student clicks on "Add"/"Drop" button?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am newbie to PHP and jQuery. I am creating an online enrollment system. One of the features in this system is that students can add and drop subjects one by one by clicking "Add" and "Drop" button respectively if a student's credit hour is more than 20 hours.

I have tried some jQuery and PHP.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add").click(function(){
$("#subjects").append('<br><br>Select Subjects(s):
<select><option value="blank"></option><option value="subject1">
Analysis and Design of Information Systems</option>
<option value="subject2">Data Communications and
Networking</option><option value="subject3">Database Development and
Applications</option><option value="subject4">Database
Systems</option><option value="subject5">DiscreteMathematics</option>
</select><br><br>Section:<select><option>Y1</option></select>');    
}); 

$("#drop").click(function(){
$("#subjects").hide(function(){
    });
});
});
```

But problem with the JavaScript script above is, when I click "Add", many selections box are added below the default one. When I click "Drop", all of the selections box (including the default one) are gone.

Basic PHP Code:

```
echo "Select Subject(s): ";
echo "<select name=subject>";
echo "<option></option>";
echo "<option>Analysis and Design of Information Systems</option>";
echo "<option>Data Communications and Networking</option>";
echo "<option>Database Development and Applications</option>";
echo "<option>Database Systems</option>";
echo "<option>Discrete Mathematics</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "Select Section: ";
echo "<select name=section>";
echo "<option>Y1</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "<form action='' method='post'><input type='submit'
name='add_button' value='Add' /> <input type='submit' name='drop_button'
value='Drop' /></form>";
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['add_button'])){
echo "Select Subject(s): ";
echo "<select name=subject>";
echo "<option></option>";
echo "<option>Analysis and Design of Information Systems</option>";
echo "<option>Data Communications and Networking</option>";
echo "<option>Database Development and Applications</option>";
echo "<option>Database Systems</option>";
echo "<option>D iscrete Mathematics</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "Select Section: ";
echo "<select name=section>";
echo "<option>Y1</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "<form action='' method='post'><input type='submit' name='add_button' value='Add' /> <input type='submit' name='drop_button' value='Drop' /></form>";
}
```

By using the PHP codes above, the selection of subject improves. If user wants to add a subject, s/he clicks "Add" button then one new selection box will be show under the default box. When s/he clicks "Drop" button, only one new selection box is gone. But the addition of the selection box only appears once. No matter how many click s/he clicks on the "Add" button, only the one selection box is showed.

Expected outcome is:

A new selection of subject will be showed every time an user clicks on the "Add" button.
A selection of subject will be erased every time an user clicks on the "Drop" button.

May I know what are the solutions to my expected results? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not adding [multiple](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple) attribute to the select and allow the user to select multiple options at once: `<select name="subject" multiple>.....your options.....</select>`?

Comment: It would be increase the chance for users to make mistakes.